# Multi language solution in Perl/Catalyst-based server

Tags: perl, catalyst, multilingual

I'm building a website using perl/catalyst and I'm bothered with multi-language problem.

I'm supposed to put the strings in a file other than perl code file(.pl .pm), and it should stay within the memory throughout the lifetime of the server.

At first I try to put it into $c->config during setup of catalyst, so I used standard perl-style file-IO `open LANG, "<file"` but I found out that after start up what's actually in the config is `pack(H*, ...)`. I don't know what happened to my string.

Some more information: All file discussed above was utf-8 encoded.

Could anyone help me or give another better solution to multi-language problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the industry standard [GNU gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext). It's supported by [CatalystX::I18N](http://p3rl.org/CatalystX%3a%3aI18N).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked up the documation and found it was exactly what I want.